# JSONArray.names() reorders the objects?

Tags: java, android, json

I have the following json returned to me from an API.

```
"sections": {
  "1": {
    "title":"Within 1 Km",
    "count":6
  },
  "3": {
    "title":"Within 3 Km",
    "count":1
  },
  ....and some more here
```

It's worth nothing this is not a JSON Array.

I need to iterate through the objects contained with sections, but because it is not a JSON array, I'm extracting the names ("1", "3", and so on) and looping through the JSON selecting each object.

```
JSONObject jsSecs = new JSONObject(data).getJSONObject("sections");
JSONArray jsSecsArray = jsSecs.names();
```

What I've noticed is that JSONArray.names() will return an array of names out of order from the JSON.

I expected 0th element to contain "1", 1st element to contain "3".

What I got was 0th element to contain "10", 2nd element to contain "1", etc - all out of sync.

What's going on here? Have I missed something obvious? I don't want to reorder things if I don't have to. It seems like more fuss than it's worth.

Comment: show us the name function plz

Comment: Just a side note: Use jakson json, and your problem is solved in one liner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html, it clearly explains:

A JSONObject is an unordered collection of name/value pairs.

Means A JSONObject does not maintain order of insertion. as lists or JSONArray has.

Comment: Well that explains it. Thanks.